# Conan story with a wizard's wall of fire

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, episode-identification, conan

I'm pretty sure at some point in the past I read a Conan story (could be from Howard or a later author) which features a scene something like the following: Conan leads an army against an opposing force. Before the battle is joined, an enemy wizard-type drives across the field of battle in a chariot, spilling what seems to be a chemical trail in a line from the back of it. Subsequently, this line springs into explosive fire as cavalry attempt to cross it.

What story is that (and chapter)?

Comment: Around what time do you think it's from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've read this—the story is "Black Colossus", and yes it was written by Howard. The country of Khoraja is threatened by an encroaching army of an evil sorcerer, a divine voice tells the Khorajan princess to save her nation she must put at the head of its army the first man she meets on the streets of her city—who happens to be the mercenary Conan. The wall of fire you describe is how the evil sorcerer disposes of Khoraja's knights (who ignore Conan's orders and charge the enemy army when it *appears* to be at a disadvantage).

Comment: The story is available at https://archive.org/stream/WeirdTalesV21n06193306IfcIbcBc#mode/2up

Comment: That's it, thanks so much!